# Increasing Value of State Variable in ForEach loop for Progress Bar in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, state

I'm trying to figure out a way to build a progress bar with React. I have a forEach loop that iterates through an array of about 7,000 indexes. Each time I validate a row, I want to update a state variable with percentage completion (and render this on the page live). I've tried iterating through these indexes, and updating my state variable (hoping to update the page) in the loop but I'm realizing that will not work. I obviously can't do this with a normal variable as it will reset when the component re-renders. Can anyone give me some insight on this topic?

Thanks.

Here is a code snippet from what I'm looking at:

```
            parsedAssets.forEach(asset => {
              newAssetValidated = validateBulkUpload(asset, parsedAssets, assetList, accountLogged, jobSites);
                !newAssetValidated.reject_err ? validatedAssetList.accepted.push(newAssetValidated) : validatedAssetList.rejected.push(newAssetValidated);
                setStateAssets({ ...stateAssets, validatedAssetList });
              });
            }
```

So essentially, as each asset is either accepted or rejected we add it to "stateAssets", and I'm hoping to build the progress bar from the length of the combined arrays that are getting set in stateAssets. However, when the forEach loop is completed, only the last validated asset is getting set due to it not updating until the forEach loop is completed.

Comment: can you show the code you tried?

Comment: Unfortunately that's how react states work: they batch updates, so you only see the final count. You might have to perform some async trick to get the progress to tick gradually. However, that means introducing some kind of artificial delay in your for loop.

Comment: Hmm... I see. Was hoping there would be some way around it without adding extra delay which doesn't seem desirable. I tried with just a loading type of GIF but that just freezes when trying to run the same loop. Not sure how to show progress here.

Comment: If this operation is going to be very heavy, I'd suggest offloading it to a service worker so it doesn't clog up your main thread. Then it's a matter of periodically emitting the progress from the service worker to your UI thread, which will then update the progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I can't imagine such a heavy validation, that you need progress-bar, but anyway.

First solution is to separate validation itself from state update for progress-bar into separate "threads". But since JS is single threaded, you may use some tricks with `setTimeout` or `setInterval` functionality. It may be very tricky, and in general not recommended practice with React.

Another way is - to set the work into queue & process 1 item at a time.

As an example I would do it something like this:

```js
function ComponentWithProgress({parsedAssets, setParsedAssets}) {
  const [validatedAssetList, setValidatedAssetList] = useState([])
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)
  const [toDo, setToDo] = useState([])
  
  if(parsedAssets && parsedAssets.length>0) {
    setToDo(parsedAssets)
    // clear parsedAssets in parent component to: [], false, null ... 
    // so you put it into toDo only once
    setParsedAssets([])
  }
  
  if(toDo.length > 0) {
    const asset = toDo[0]
    const newToDo = toDo.slice(1) // All but 0th element 
    
    const newAssetValidated = validateBulkUpload(asset);
        
    setValidatedAssetList([ ...validatedAssetList, newAssetValidated ]);
    setToDo(newToDo)
    setProgress( newToDo.length / ( validatedAssetList.length + newToDo.length ) * 100 )
  }

  // ... Render here        
  
  // If you need only accepted
  const accepted = validatedAssetList.filter(v => !v.reject_err)
  
}
```

This example maybe not work for you as is, because you didn't showed us the context, but the main idea is here.

Comment: Other than creating a progress bar, how would you approach the rendering of a component while it is waiting (potentially ~8 seconds) to complete the action of parsing/validating thousands of rows before rendering results? @oleg

Comment: You just put rendering code of completed component & rendering code of 'in progress' component inside separate sections of 'if'.  Like:  `if(progress<100) { renderInProgressComponent() } else { renderFinishedComponent() }`